# Bootstrap tabs screwing up google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a map that is inside a bootstrap tabs.
I initiate the map when I go to that tab

```
$('.locations').click(function(){
    setTimeout(initMap(),1500);
});
```

Heres the init function

```
function initMap() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10.0,5.0);

    var myOptions = {
       zoom: 2,
       center: myLatlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions); 
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    });

  }
```

The map loads fine when I visit the tab for the first time.  But if I click to another tab, and then back.  It just shows a blank grey screen (still with the Google logo, which is wierd)

Ive had this happen in the past, but usually it dissappears fully, or resizes, and I have to just re-adjust.  But this time, it seems the map isnt totally gone.

Its there, its just grey.  Almost as if its just zoomed in real far, and I cant unzoom it.  How can I either re-initialize it from scratch when I click the tab again, or get it to come back?

Right now, its firing the init function every time I click the tab.  If I make it so it doesnt do that, it still shows the grey screen after.  Which you would think after initializing, it would be fine??? I dont get it.

[image]

Comment: Is this a rails app? Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: no straight html, no backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to get rid of `setTimeout` function for initializing google maps since there is no any guarantee that Google Maps API is getting loaded after the specified delay. Google Maps API provides its own ways to control whether google maps is loaded. In the following example:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

google maps is getting initialized once the page has finished loading.

Here is a working example that demonstrates how to initialize a map in bootstap tab.

**Example**

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10.0, 5.0);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  
  //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}


$(function(){


  $("a[href='#locations']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
      initMap();
  });


});
```

```css
#map {
        height: 480px;
        width: 640px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>


<div>


<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#locations" data-toggle="tab">Locations</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
    HOME
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="locations">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why the simple change of this.... $(".locationsTab").click(function() {initMap();});  to $("a[href='#locations']").on('shown.bs.tab', function() {initMap();});  would make the map appear??  what is shown.bs.tab doing?  forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

Modify your timeout to pass in the `initMap` function as a callback like so:

```
setTimeout(initMap,1500);
```

Currently you are calling `initMap()` immediately, on click, and the timeout is not being used at all.